# Is it okay to use photos of Facebook users who have liked my page on a web site?

Tags: facebook-like, photos

I am the webmaster for a large online school. On our visitors page I would like to use the photos of Facebook users who have liked our page. The photos would be used in a header graphic, and would not be altered in anyway. Is this okay?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

No. Without permission it is ethically wrong.

Comment: Thank you. It's not a significant portion of the web site, or really used for any personal or financial gain. It's just that contacting all of the users, and getting a reply, may take some time and delay the posting of the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Go for it.

Your users may detest you, but they had the opportunity to read the Facebook [Data Use Policy](http://www.facebook.com/full_data_use_policy) before starting use of the service:

> Information you choose to make public Choosing to make your
>   information public is exactly what it sounds like: anyone, including
>   people off of Facebook, will be able to see it. Choosing to make your
>   information public also means that this information:
>
> - can be associated with you (i.e., your name, profile picture, Facebook profile, User ID, etc.) even off Facebook
> - can show up when someone does a search on Facebook or on a public search engine
> - will be accessible to the games, applications, and websites you and your friends use
> - will be accessible to anyone who uses our APIs such as our Graph API.

Comment: +1 for reminding my once more why I do not have a facebook account.

Comment: I did read the Facebook Data Use policy, but wasn't sure about the interpretation. Thank you for making it a little more clear. (Our users probably won't detest us, rather they'll most likely think it's cool to have their face shown on the school web site).

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't provide an API of who likes your page so it will be difficult for you to get a complete list.  However Facebook provides social plugins that will show the pictures of who likes a page so I don't see why you wouldnt be able to do this.

Comment: I did try the Facepile plugin, but wanted to show a set number of users, instead of only those users and their friends that were currently logged in. Thanks for the reply.